# C# Connecting to SQL Server using exe

Tags: c#, sql-server, exe

My goal is to create a stand-alone C# Windows form application which will connect to SQL Server.

I have to deploy this stand-alone file in different client machine.

Consider I have two machines - Machine A and B.

On Machine A, I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and VS2013 for development.

Connection string I have used for development:

```
Data Source=AssetName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test_Database;Integrated Security=True
```

which is working fine on Machine A. When I tried the same on Machine B it is not connecting to SQL Server on Machine A.

When I searched on internet, I got many references suggesting to use service-based database in VS. However I am finding difficult to understand how service-based database is working. I couldn't see any connectivity between the server and service-based database.

Can anyone help me with this?

Also please let me know to connect the SQL Server on Machine A do I need to use SQL Server Management Studio on Machine B?

Error msg:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while extablishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: All you need is to configure the server to allow connections from the other machine. This is explained in the documentation. Do note that if you use Windows accounts you'll most likely need to be in a domain for them to work properly without a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

try to configure your server in machine A to allow access from other machines.
generally you have to use your machine A  adress ip as a server name  with  sql server instance name to connect from other machine.

Comment: On top: FIREWALL. Setting up SQL Server does NOT add a firewall rule - so the firewall stops all incoming access.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server **Express** doesn't allow remote connections by default - you need to *explicitly enable* this feature.

To do so, use these steps:

- in SQL Server Management Studio, go to the Object Explorer
- right-click on the top-level node (which represents the SQL Server Express instance - usually labeled `......\SQLEXPRESS`)
- in the `Properties` dialog, go to the `Connections` tab on the left side
- check the option checkbox `Allow remote connectìons`

[image]

- restart your SQL Server Express instance

Now you should be able to connect to this SQL Server Express instance from a remote machine using `MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS` as the server/instance name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with ready proven MS-SQL client, I use MS SQL Management Studio.
Connection window has few options, You can check i.e. firewall is blocking access, "broadcast" naming service is active etc.
Maybe problem is not at client side, but server side (TCP-IP disabled, non listening on IP range ... many more situations).

Who is administrator of SQL Server? What with 1433 port? Is TCP-IP enabled? Default on most versions is not.

On next stage Management will be usefull i.e. to design queries etc.